# How can I update my iOS app in real time?

Tags: ios7

I'm a beginner to iOS development. I want to create an application that produces one interesting fact everyday. Is there a web service or any API that I can use to update the app in real time. Any relevant tutorial would be helpful.

Comment: The terms "update the app in real time" is a bit misleading and sounds like you want to update the program code (i.e. the app bundle).  But to (half) answer your question, then yes you would need to set-up a web service of some kind for the app to talk to in order to get today's fact.

Comment: When you say "real-time" do you mean that it says one thing at 11:59pm, then the display automatically changes at midnight? Or is it okay if the interesting fact updates when the App launches?

Comment: I want something like,
23rd-May-2014 : Fact #1
24th-May-2014(after 12midnight technically): Fact #2.
So ya the display should automatically change at midnight and there should be one unique fact for every single day.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a server and will need to write some server-side code.  You could create a REST service to provide your new fact of the day.

Try this tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/58682/introduction-restkit-tutorial